# Why does PHP ftp_connect fail when the server is running?

Tags: php, ftp, connection-timeout

I've been trying to connect via FTP to my server for some time now and can't seem to get it to work.

```
$connection_id = ftp_connect("example.com", 22);
```

When running this code, it hangs for sometime until PHP eventually tells me the script has been executing for too long and quits. It does not fail and return FALSE. It just times out.

My first instinct was that maybe the server was down, so I pinged it. The ping was successful and I didn't lose any packets. Then I tried using the **same parameters to connect with Filezilla and it was able to connect**. I can also SSH to the server. I even tried extending the execution time PHP allows for the script but it always hangs up and times out.

So what stumps me is that if all these methods of connecting to the server work, then why won't ftp_connect() function work?

**CLARIFICATION:**

Some of you have wondered why am I using port 22 (the SSH port) for connecting. I tried the default port for FTP (Port 21) at first, but the ftp_connect() function immediately returned FALSE, which according to the PHP manual means there was some error.

I was also *unable* to connect through Port 21 with FileZilla. So I decided to use the SFTP Port instead, which is Port 22. Doing this connected successfully in FileZilla.

Comment: FTP servers are normally on port 21. Port 22 is usually SSH.

Comment: It sounds like the server isn't running an FTP server. Port 22 isn't the SFTP port, it's SSH. Maybe you're thinking of SCP, which performs file transfers over SSH. You can't use an FTP client for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ftp_connect` is not meant to be used for connecting to SFTP servers.  Check out [`ssh2_sftp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php), which uses a different methodology then standard FTP.

Answer (score 0):

A third parameter was added to the function called `timeout`.  Try something like:

```
$conn = ftp_connect('site', 22, 360);
```

Comment: `I even tried extending the execution time PHP allows for the script but it always hangs up and times out.` - The OP already tried that.

Comment: @AmalMurali There are a couple ways to change execution time (or timeout), he never specified which one.

Comment: @julienhaversano Thanks for your input. I actually used the PHP function set_time_limit() at the beginning of my script to set the execution time limit. Should it make a significant difference to specify it in the ftp_connect() function instead?

Comment: @Jamil I think it's worth a shot, probably the only thing actually stopping the connection is the timeout.  By default it's set to 90, so unless the server is incredibly slow, you shouldn't need to set it.

Comment: @julienhaversano I have extended both the script time and the timeout of the ftp_connect() to more than 5 minutes. This time, using port 22, I get a conclusive failure from the function instead of a timeout.

That is some progress (I think), but it still doesn't explain why it won't connect while FileZilla can. Puzzling.

Answer (score -1):

may be you can try to use "IP" address rather then entire string.

Comment: If you can ping the hostname, changing it to use the IP address won't do anything.